# Mail sending issue form Contact form

Tags: magento-1.9, email, contact-us

I have set up an Email Account in outlook. I sent from outlook to my self 
 an email and it works fine

I use the same Settings in Magento Configuration- System in SMTP PRO EMAIL, but the contact form produce an error There has been an error processing your request

If I reproduce this with the other email it works fine

Comment: Magento version?

Comment: the verion is Magento 1.9

Comment: what's the error showing

Comment: Trace:
#0 /home/ledguru/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mirasvit_Helpdesk_FormController->postAction()
#1 /home/ledguru/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('post')

Comment: #3 /home/ledguru/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#4 /home/ledguru/public_html/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#5 /home/ledguru/public_html/gr/index.php(103): Mage::run('oneguru4you_gre...', 'store')
#6 {main}